# HTML doctype declaration in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a very strange problem in JSF page that I cannot solve. I have this html doctype declaration into the xhtml page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
```

When I run the JSF page and I open Furebug to the page code I get this:

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body>
</html>
```

It should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body>
</html>
```

I don't know why the html doctype is skipped? Can you help me to fix this?

P.S I use JSF navigation to navigate to the new page:

```
    <h:commandButton id="newdatacenter" styleClass="lbimage" value="New Datacenter" action="#{DatacentersController.navigateToNewDatacenter()}">
     //   <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>

 // Navigate to New Datacenter page
    public int navigateToNewDatacenter(){
        return 11432;
    }

    <navigation-rule>
        <description>Navigation rule to New Datacenter page</description>
        <from-view-id>/DatacentersList.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{DatacentersController.navigateToNewDatacenter()}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>11432</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/NewDatacenter.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

I don't know why when the new JSF page is opened the HTML doctype declaration is not included.

Comment: It's called "HTML doctype declaration", not "HTML standard declaration".

Answer (score 0):

Recent Mojarra versions have a bug which causes the doctype to be removed in the rendered HTML. This seems to occur if included files define a doctype on their own. If you use an affected version (<2.1.14), you might want to check

[Doctype not rendered in the generated HTML if doctype was defined in an included file](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2453)